# Trying to find nodes in binary tree

Tags: python, binary-tree

I am trying to find nodeA and nodeB in a binary tree branch. I am returning a sum that should equal the number of nodes found. Here is my implementation

```
def checkSubtree(self, nodeA, nodeB, node):
        if node is None:
            return 0
        if node is nodeA or node is nodeB:
            return 1
        return self.checkSubtree(nodeA, nodeB, node.leftChild) + self.checkSubtree(nodeA, nodeB, node.rightChild)
```

I keep getting 1 when i should be getting 2. I figured out that its because the second if statement is executed on the first pass and returns immediately.

How do I improve this. I do not want to use an extra variable to store the result and return that.

Answer (score 1):

`nodeA` or `nodeB` nodes could still have children, which could possibly be `nodeA` or `nodeB` nodes.

With `return 1`, you stopped your recursive search as soon as you encountered a `nodeA` or `nodeB` node.

One solution would be:

```
def checkSubtree(self, nodeA, nodeB, node):
    if node is None:
        return 0
    else:
        children_sum = self.checkSubtree(nodeA, nodeB, node.leftChild) + self.checkSubtree(nodeA, nodeB, node.rightChild)
        if node is nodeA or node is nodeB:
            return 1 + children_sum # <-- Important. Not just 1 !
        else:
            return children_sum
```

If for whatever reason you do now want to define a local variable:

```
def checkSubtree(self, nodeA, nodeB, node):
    if node is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return self.checkSubtree(nodeA, nodeB, node.leftChild) + self.checkSubtree(
            nodeA, nodeB, node.rightChild) + int(node is nodeA or node is nodeB)
```

Comment: Can you explain that with code? I didn't follow you

Comment: The last part of my post said "I do not want to use an extra variable to store the result and return that". So I am assuming theres no way to do this without using an extra variable?

Comment: @ZaidHumayun Why would you want to use an extra variable when you don't need to.

Comment: @ZaidHumayun: Having a correct answer seems more important to me than not using an extra variable. Still, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - I said I don't want to use an extra variable.

Comment: @EricDuminil - I get that. Its just that I initially tried this without using an extra variable before finding a solution using a variable. I just wanted to see if it was possible the first way. Thanks for the extra effort!